# OSQA Reaching to Page Files (Bitnami)

Tags: python, bitnami, osqa

I've been trying to reach to OSQA pages to modify them. I've installed it to my pc with bitnami and I cannot find the files of the pages. I couldn't find anything on the wiki and readme files.

Is there a way to edit the pages? Not just css but also I'm going to add more stuff to it.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you install a Bitnami Stack the files of the application, OSQA in this case, are in `/installdir/apps/osqa/htdocs`, just changing `installdir` with the directory where you installed the stack. For instance on windows it is installed by default on `C:\Bitnami\osqa\apps\osqa\htdocs`.

On the `\installdir\osqa` directory you will find on `htdocs` the application files like .css, .py ... and on `conf` the configuration files of apache, so if you want to add more subdirectories or change any directives you should take a look here. If you want to edit any feature of the application you should go to the `htdocs` directory and edit the python files in order to achieve your developments.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I'll try these :)